# Bearer token works with ADAL, does not work with MSAL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a protected Web API running that I would like to access. In Azure the App Registration is:

- SPA with tenant admin permissions to the Web API
- Web API does not have tenant admin permissions thus requesting a token for it's id will return the "app needs permissions to access resources" error

I'm trying to get a bearer token for the Web API. The problem is that it won't work with MSAL, but it does work with ADAL.

Here is the ADAL vanilla JS code of my "SPA":

```js
window.config = {
   clientId: 'SPA client id',
   tenant: 'Tenant id',
   redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
   extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
   popUp: true
};


var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);

function getToken(){
    var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
    if (!user) {
        authContext.login();
        return;
    }
    var cachedToken = authContext.getCachedToken(window.config.endpoints.prod);
    if (!cachedToken) {
        authContext.acquireToken("Web API Client Id", function(error, token) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
    console.log(cachedToken);
    var t = document.getElementById("token");
    t.innerText = cachedToken;
};
```

If I copy the token in Postman and do a request it will work.

The MSAL code is as follows:

```js
const msalConfig = {
      auth: {
                clientId: "SPA client id",
                authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/Tenant id"
            }
        };

const loginRequest = {
       scopes: ["copied the scope of SPA from the Expose API"],
       redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/"
};
 const myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
myMSALObj.loginPopup(loginRequest).then(handleResponse).catch(function (error) { console.log(error);});
var tokenRequest = {
             scopes: ["Copied scope from the Web API expose API section"],
            };
            if (!token) {
                myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(tokenRequest)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        setTimeout(function () { 
                        token = response.accessToken;
                    });
    console.log(token);
```

Now there is one thing I noticed as a difference: `ADAL` allows me to pass on the Client Id of the Web Api when calling the acquireToken method while `MSAL` does not. Could not find any documentation on it but I presume it resolved it from the Application Id Uri.

The second difference is in the token claim aud:

- ADAL aud is the Web API Client Id
- MSAL aud is the Web API Application Id Uri

Comment: What's the error reported by MSAL? I try [the sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-graphapi-v2) and it works well.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. It looks like MSAL works when I use the AppId/scope in the scopes[] and the App Registration had the scope in the form of AppIdUri/scope. I don't know why the AppIdUri did not work but I presume the API to be configured to only accept it's own App Id and not it's App Id Uri. Why is it's scope (in the expose the API section) written like this? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

There are two identifiers for the app, the `AppId` in the form of xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx and `AppIdURI` which is given by the user.

If I use the scope `xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx\user.read` it works. I was using the scope in the form of `AppIdURI\user.read`. Thus the tokens were the same except for the `aud`, where ADAL had the Client Id (aka App Id) and MSAL had the AppIdURI. Changed it to AppId and it works.

I don't know why the app won't accept the AppIdUri because in the `Expose an API` section the scope is written as `AppIdUri/user.read`.